# In Scala, why could remainder (%) operator return a negative number?

Tags: java, scala, modulo

For example, `(-3) % 2` will return `-1` instead of `1`.

What is the preferred way to get the positive remainder in Scala? Such as `(((-3) % 2) + 2) % 2`, or `abs(-3 % 2)`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> In scala, why could remainder (%) operator return a negative number?

There are different conventions for the sign of the result of a modulo operation; [Wikipedia has a good article on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). Scala, like most but by no means all programming languages, has the result take the sign of the dividend (the `-3` in your case).

> What is the preferred way to get the positive remainder in Scala?

I doubt there's a generally-agreed preferred way; if it were me, either use [`Math.floorMod`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod-int-int-), which gives a result with the sign of the divisor (`2` in your example) instead of the dividend (this doesn't just mean the same value as `%` with a different sign, see the linked JavaDoc for details). Or just an `if` afterward (`if (result < 0) { result += M; }` [where `M` is the divisor, `2` in your example]).

Comment: Is it a shame `floorMod` is defined only for `int` and `long`, not for `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 16):

The correct way to get the positive modulus is to add the divisor to the negative modulus:

```
(-18 % 5) + 5
```

Taking the absolute value will give you the wrong solution in this case, though it will work if the divisor happens to be 2.

If you don't know the sign of the dividend, you can do something like this:

```
((dividend % divisor) + divisor) % divisor
```

Comment: small nit: 'r = dividend % divisor; if (r < 0) r + divisor else r' is somewhat more efficient than taking another %

Comment: @yonil: Eh... I'm skeptical.  While the modulo operator is not as efficient as (for example) addition, I find it hard to believe that it is materially slower than a conditional branch.  Regardless, your compiler should be smart enough to transform either version into the other as appropriate.

Comment: There is no branch there. It gets compiled to CPU instructions that perform bitwise manipulation

Comment: Also, I would not trust the compiler to understand the second modulo operation can be eliminated, because it requires reasoning about the actual arithmetic (e.g. won't happen, unless a suitable optimization rule was added _specifically_ to handle expressions of this form)

Comment: @yonil: Compilers are pretty smart these days.  I suspect it would break each modulo apart into "if the dividend is positive" and "if the dividend is negative" cases and analyze them separately.  That's an obvious peephole optimization that I thought of in five minutes.  Surely compiler writers are aware of it.

Comment: @yonil: If you think you have a better answer to this question, then please answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

Using `math.abs(-x % y)` does not usually yield the same behavior as returning a positive modulus:

```
scala> math.abs(-7 % 3)
res46: Int = 1
```

But that's not what python (a language that returns a positive modulus) says:

```
In [14]: -7 % 3
Out[14]: 2
```

If we look at increments of 3 from -7:

```
-7, -4, -1, 2, ..
```

`scala` stops at `-1`, and `python` stops at `2`.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add something to the existing answers. My preferred way to get the positive remainder is to add a new method to the Int type as follows:

```
object Extensions
{
    implicit class ExtendedInt (val i: Int) extends AnyVal {
        def positiveMod (m: Int) = {val x = i % m; if (x < 0) x + m else x}
    }
}
```

In the file where you want to use the method, import the implicit class with:

```
import Extensions._
```

Now you can do:

```
(-3).positiveMod(2)
```

You could also put the implicit class in a package object so you don't need to import when calling the function from the same package.

Answer (score -2):

For example, if you want to filter out all odd elements from an array, ignoring negative or positive, you can do like this:

> arr.filter{x => Math.abs(x%2)==1}